# odd syntax for getting the size of a member in a class

Tags: c++

I ran into some code that looks like the following:

```
#define SIZE_M(klass, mem)     sizeof( ((klass*)0)->mem )
```

I'm unfamiliar with the syntax `(klass*)0)` and what its purpose is. It's dereferencing the pointer to member `mem`, but is the trick with the `0` here taking a default in the event mem doesn't exist?

Comment: Actual expression is not evaluated.

Comment: [**`sizeof`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) doesn't work the way (and more to the point, *when*) you think it does.

Comment: How else would you write it? `sizeof(mem)` won't work, because `mem` isn't in scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `((klass*)0)` is a *cast*.  We are casting the expression 0 from its usual type to a type of `klass*`, which means it will be a pointer to whatever `klass` is.  The purpose of writing that expression is that we needed an object of type `klass*` but we didn't know how to get one, because different classes have different restrictions on how they can be constructed.  So we are kind of cheating and making this null pointer and telling the compiler that it has a type of `klass*`.  Then we can get one of the members in that fake object and ask the compiler how large it is using `sizeof`.  The `sizeof(...)` expression is all evaluated at compile time.